# Create 15*15 Matrix of Custom View using Horizontal and Vertical Scroll View?

Tags: android, scrollview, horizontal-scrolling, vertical-scrolling

I need to implement 15 * 15 matrix of **Custom View** (ImageView + TextView) which will Scroll(Move) any direction:

- Horizontal
- Vertical
- Diagonal

Code is working fine and Scroll-able in both direction smoothly.

***Issue occur:***

Now I need to take a click on View which will have a name ***ll_box***, this is a custom view which is mentioned above.

```
ll_box.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), globalData.arrayListDetail.get(Integer.parseInt(v.getTag().toString())).detail, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
});
```

`When a apply setOnClickListener on ll_box, app load the data but its freezes. Horizontal & Verticall Scrollview not working , if I remove that code working fine.`

**`Please let me know how can we manage it properly.`** Below is the code which I using for creating ll_box(Custom View).

---

**Working Code:**

```
public void llView(){
   int count = globalData.arrayListDetail.size() / 15;
   int total = 0;

   int w_h = (int)((getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density) * 150);

   for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        LinearLayout ll_horizontal = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
        ll_horizontal.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        ll_horizontal.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        for (int j = 0; j < 15; j++) {
                LinearLayout ll_box  = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp_ll = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                lp_ll.setMargins(5, 5, 5, 5);
                ll_box.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.layout_border));
                ll_box.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
                ll_box.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                ll_box.setLayoutParams(lp_ll);

            // If I use it , View Freezes : not move horizontal or vertical (taking much memory, How can manage this thing)
            /*ll_box.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), globalData.arrayListDetail.get(Integer.parseInt(v.getTag().toString())).detail, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });*/

            ImageView imageView = new ImageView(getActivity());
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(w_h, w_h);
            lp.setMargins(5, 5, 5, 5);
            imageView.setBackgroundColor(Color.DKGRAY);
            imageLoader.DisplayImage(globalData.arrayListDetail.get(total).img_src, 0, imageView);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(lp);

            TextView textView = new TextView(getActivity());
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp_TextView = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(w_h, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            lp_TextView.setMargins(5, 0, 5, 5);
            textView.setText(globalData.arrayListDetail.get(total).name);
            textView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.detail_theme_color));
            textView.setSingleLine();
            textView.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.END);
            textView.setLayoutParams(lp_TextView);

            total = total + 1;

            ll_box.addView(imageView);
            ll_box.addView(textView);

            ll_horizontal.addView(ll_box);
        }
        ll_vertical.addView(ll_horizontal);
    }
}
```

---

ll_horizontal will make the 1 * 15 view

ll_vertical will make 15 * 15 view

ll_vertical is a part of HorizontalScrollView and HorizontaollScrollView is added into the ScrollView in Layout XML file.

**`Solution:`**

I used **onTouch** to resolve the freezes occurrence

Comment: `app load the data but its freezes` because you are loading data on main  thread

Comment: llView() calling from AsyncTask @KaranMer

Comment: show the code then, from where you are calling this method

Comment: seeing from the code of your llview() it contains a lot of UI operations. If you would have placed this in doinbackground() of asynctask it would not run and would have given you an error.

Comment: yes, I skip the AsyncTask and was using  runOnUiThread @KaranMer

Comment: I added in the AsyncTask but doinbackground will not  update the UI. So I used the runOnuiThread , As I mentioned if I commented the ll_box.setOnClickListener . In that time App working fine @KaranMer

Comment: you can load your data in background and update your UI in onPostexecute()

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89170/discussion-between-a-m-and-karan-mer). @KaranMer

Comment: Not working same issue occur  @KaranMer

Comment: What happens if you just put "Hello World!" in the Toast ?

Comment: @StephaneMathis: Toast working fine but after adding ll_box.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { , memory increase  and view freezes but after few sec if I try to move something work or sometime not after this again freez

Comment: What are you doing in `globalData.arrayListDetail.get(Integer.parseInt(v.getTag().toString())).detail` ? It looks like this part takes a few seconds to execute and make the UI freeze as well as consuming memory.

Comment: Toast will call when I click on the ll_box , that is a separate thing. If I will Pass only "Hello" as I did it starting the same problem occur. @StephaneMathis

Comment: Oh, ok. And without a Toast, just write something in the log, does your problem occur ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89174/discussion-between-a-m-and-stephane-mathis).

Comment: not any freezes occur @StephaneMathis